# Dropdown submenu not recognizing click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this menu that if the page width can't hold all of its items those remaining items are added to a more option.

The thing is, I can't open links when I click on a submenu from the more option. Here's an example which logs the link when clicked.

```js
$(".top_menu li").click(function() {

  console.log($(this).data('link'));

  // Checks if there is a link
  if (typeof $(this).data('link') !== 'undefined') {
    //document.location.href = $(this).data('link');
  }
});
$(".top_menu ul").each(function() {
  alignMenu(this);
  var robj = this;
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(robj).append($($($(robj).children("li.hideshow")).children("ul")).html());
    $(robj).children("li.hideshow").remove();
    alignMenu(robj);
  });

  function alignMenu(obj) {
    var w = 0;
    var mw = $(obj).width() - 150;
    var i = -1;
    var menuhtml = '';
    jQuery.each($(obj).children(), function() {
      i++;
      w += $(this).outerWidth(true);
      if (mw < w) {
        menuhtml += $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html();
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
    $(obj).append('<li class="hideshow">MORE&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i><ul>' + menuhtml + '</ul></li>');
    $(obj).children("li.hideshow ul").css("top", $(obj).children("li.hideshow").outerHeight(true) + "px");

    // Opens the menu
    $(obj).children(".hideshow").click(function() {
      $(this).find("ul").animate({
        height: 'toggle'
      }, 'fast');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.top_menu {
  width: 100%;
}

ul.horizontal-menu,
.horizontal-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.horizontal-menu {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #616161;
}

.horizontal-menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .218s;
  -moz-transition: border .218s;
  -o-transition: border-color .218s;
  transition: border-color .218s;
  background: #616161;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.horizontal-menu li .material-icons {
  margin: -10px;
}

.hideshow ul li {
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.horizontal-menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(246, 83, 20);
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  background: #484848;
}

.horizontal-menu li.hideshow ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: -203px;
  width: 300px;
}

.horizontal-menu li.hideshow {
  position: relative;
}

.hideshow ul {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  background: #616161;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Material Icons (Google) -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="top_menu">
  <ul class="horizontal-menu">
    <li>&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">search</i>&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 1</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 2</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 3</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 4</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 5</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 6</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 7</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 8</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 9</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 10</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 11</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 12</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 13</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 14</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do event delegation as your li's are getting added dynamically

```
$(".top_menu li").click(function() {...
```

The above code will add event listener to `li` directly which will cause problem as you are rearranging the `li` in the DOM dynamically.

You have to use event delegation.

```
$(".top_menu").on('click','li[data-link]',function() {...
```

This code will add event listener to `top-menu` but delegate the event to all its decedent `li` with selector `li[data-link]`

Read about [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Check out my this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155068/event-listener-after-ajax-refresh/44155173?noredirect=1#answer-44155173) for explanation on event delegation
.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(".top_menu").on('click','li[data-link]',function() {

  console.log($(this).data('link'));

  // Checks if there is a link
  if (typeof $(this).data('link') !== 'undefined') {
    //document.location.href = $(this).data('link');
  }
});
$(".top_menu ul").each(function() {
  alignMenu(this);
  var robj = this;
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(robj).append($($($(robj).children("li.hideshow")).children("ul")).html());
    $(robj).children("li.hideshow").remove();
    alignMenu(robj);
  });

  function alignMenu(obj) {
    var w = 0;
    var mw = $(obj).width() - 150;
    var i = -1;
    var menuhtml = '';
    jQuery.each($(obj).children(), function() {
      i++;
      w += $(this).outerWidth(true);
      if (mw < w) {
        menuhtml += $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html();
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
    $(obj).append('<li class="hideshow">MORE&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i><ul>' + menuhtml + '</ul></li>');
    $(obj).children("li.hideshow ul").css("top", $(obj).children("li.hideshow").outerHeight(true) + "px");

    // Opens the menu
    $(obj).children(".hideshow").click(function() {
      $(this).find("ul").animate({
        height: 'toggle'
      }, 'fast');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.top_menu {
  width: 100%;
}

ul.horizontal-menu,
.horizontal-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.horizontal-menu {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #616161;
}

.horizontal-menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .218s;
  -moz-transition: border .218s;
  -o-transition: border-color .218s;
  transition: border-color .218s;
  background: #616161;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.horizontal-menu li .material-icons {
  margin: -10px;
}

.hideshow ul li {
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.horizontal-menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(246, 83, 20);
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  background: #484848;
}

.horizontal-menu li.hideshow ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: -203px;
  width: 300px;
}

.horizontal-menu li.hideshow {
  position: relative;
}

.hideshow ul {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  background: #616161;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Material Icons (Google) -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="top_menu">
  <ul class="horizontal-menu">
    <li>&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">search</i>&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 1</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 2</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 3</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 4</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 5</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 6</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 7</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 8</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 9</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 10</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 11</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 12</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 13</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 14</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `$(".top_menu li").click(...)` function only applies to the li elements that exist at that time, and your code is removing and reattaching them to the dom later on. In order to attach to any li elements with a link that exist at that time or later, you can use the `.on('click', selector, ...)`. And to avoid including the li.hideshow element you can use `li[data-link]` as the selector.

```js
$(".top_menu").on('click', 'li[data-link]', function() {

  console.log($(this).data('link'));

  // Checks if there is a link
  if (typeof $(this).data('link') !== 'undefined') {
    //document.location.href = $(this).data('link');
  }
});
$(".top_menu ul").each(function() {
  alignMenu(this);
  var robj = this;
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(robj).append($($($(robj).children("li.hideshow")).children("ul")).html());
    $(robj).children("li.hideshow").remove();
    alignMenu(robj);
  });

  function alignMenu(obj) {
    var w = 0;
    var mw = $(obj).width() - 150;
    var i = -1;
    var menuhtml = '';
    jQuery.each($(obj).children(), function() {
      i++;
      w += $(this).outerWidth(true);
      if (mw < w) {
        menuhtml += $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html();
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
    $(obj).append('<li class="hideshow">MORE&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i><ul>' + menuhtml + '</ul></li>');
    $(obj).children("li.hideshow ul").css("top", $(obj).children("li.hideshow").outerHeight(true) + "px");

    // Opens the menu
    $(obj).children(".hideshow").click(function() {
      $(this).find("ul").animate({
        height: 'toggle'
      }, 'fast');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.top_menu {
  width: 100%;
}

ul.horizontal-menu,
.horizontal-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.horizontal-menu {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #616161;
}

.horizontal-menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .218s;
  -moz-transition: border .218s;
  -o-transition: border-color .218s;
  transition: border-color .218s;
  background: #616161;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.horizontal-menu li .material-icons {
  margin: -10px;
}

.hideshow ul li {
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.horizontal-menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(246, 83, 20);
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  background: #484848;
}

.horizontal-menu li.hideshow ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: -203px;
  width: 300px;
}

.horizontal-menu li.hideshow {
  position: relative;
}

.hideshow ul {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  background: #616161;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Material Icons (Google) -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="top_menu">
  <ul class="horizontal-menu">
    <li>&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">search</i>&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 1</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 2</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 3</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 4</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 5</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 6</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 7</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 8</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 9</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 10</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 11</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 12</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 13</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 14</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your event trigger is not correct. You can change it into the below or add a class to the other ul.

```
$("li").click(function() {
```

Comment: This actually won't work as this click function would still only apply to the elements that exist when this code is run. All this does is make it apply to elements outside of his menu also.